# How to add error bars in matplotlib for multiple groups from dataframe?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

I've run multiple regressions and stored the coefficients and standard errors into a data frame like this:

[image: Data frame]

I wanted to make a graph that shows how the coefficient changes for each group over time, like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))

sns.set(style= "whitegrid")

sns.lineplot(x="time", y="coef",
             hue="group",
             data=eventstudy)
plt.axhline(y=0 , color='r', linestyle='--')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=2)
plt.show
plt.savefig('eventstudygraph.png')
```

Which produces:
[image]

But I would like to include error bars using the 'stderr' data from my main data set. 
I think I can do it using 'plt.errorbar'. But can't seem to figure out how to make it work. At the moment, I've tried adding the 'plt.errorbar line and experimenting different with different iterations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))

sns.set(style= "whitegrid")

sns.lineplot(x="time", y="coef",
             hue="group",
             data=eventstudy)
plt.axhline(y=0 , color='r', linestyle='--')
plt.errorbar("time", "coef", xerr="stderr", data=eventstudy)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=2)
plt.show
plt.savefig('eventstudygraph.png')
```

[image]

As you can see, it seems to be creating it's own group/line in the graph. I think I would know how to use 'plt.errorbar' if I had just one group, but I don't have a clue how to make it work for 3 groups. Is there some way of making 3 versions of 'plt.errorbar' so I can create the error bars for each group separately? Or is there something simpler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to iterate through the different groups, and plot the errorbar separately, what you have above is plotting all the error bars at one go:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
np.random.seed(111)
df = pd.DataFrame({"time":[1,2,3,4,5]*3,"coef":np.random.uniform(-0.5,0.5,15),
                   "stderr":np.random.uniform(0.05,0.1,15),
                   "group":np.repeat(['Monthly','3 Monthly','6 Monthly'],5)})

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))
sns.set(style= "whitegrid")
lvls = df.group.unique()
for i in lvls:
    ax.errorbar(x = df[df['group']==i]["time"],
                y=df[df['group']==i]["coef"], 
                yerr=df[df['group']==i]["stderr"],label=i)
ax.axhline(y=0 , color='r', linestyle='--')
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Once again StupidWolf, you've come to my rescue and I am so grateful. I did not even realise you could add for loops into the matplotlib configuration, so I'm sure this will be handy in the future.

Comment: The colour of the lines are different from what is shown on the legend. It has done the same thing in the solution you provided. I'm sure I can investigate to figure this out, but just wanted to flag it for others. (Will update if I solve it)

Comment: @Jameson, thanks for pointing it out! You are right, it plots over again. The plt.errorbar function joins the lines if your x values are continuous.. so yeah you don't need the sns.lineplot to start with...

Comment: Amazing. Thanks! I did suspect this to be the case but didn't know how to rectify it without sacrificing the legend itself.