# Plot multiple errorbars from dataframe to scatter plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe with areas in one column, density values in one column and unique standard error, SE, values in one column.  I want to use these in a scatterplot - dates in Datetime format on the x-axis, density on the y-axis, and standard error as errorbars in the y direction (referred to as yerr).

I keep getting problems regarding the type of the yerr  - "yerr must be a scalar or a 1D or (2, n) array-like".

How do I add multiple yerrors from a Dataframe, to a scatterplot with Datetime?

I have tried selecting the yerrors from the dataframe several ways. I have also tried just making a list manually with the yerrors, but that didn't work. I also tried making a loop similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62177520/how-to-add-error-bars-in-matplotlib-for-multiple-groups-from-dataframe), but didn't succeed. This is what I have now (please let me know if I need to add more info for you to understand the problem):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot
import datetime


#Creating dataframe for the StackOverflow Example
data = [['RN',0.0, 0.0], ['RO',26.52, 10.51], ['RN',12.43, 5.56], ['CS',0.0,0.0]]
dfvideo = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Area','Density', 'SE'])

#Selecting the area, i.e. "RN", that I want the density and yerror (SE) for.
RNvid = dfvideo.loc[(dfvideo["Area"]=="RN"),["Density"]]
RNvidSE = dfvideo.loc[(dfvideo["Area"]=="RN"),["SE"]]

#Converting dates in dataframe to DateTime
dfvideodate = pd.to_datetime(dfvideo["Date"], format='%Y-%m-%d')


#Trying to plot
fig, axis_1 = plt.subplots(figsize =(15, 4))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

RNax2= axis_1.errorbar(dfvideodate.loc[[0,2]], RNvid, color="r",yerr=RNvidSE, fmt="-o",capsize=3, elinewidth=0.5, label = "RN Video") 



#Parameters for x-ticks and labels
years = plt.matplotlib.dates.YearLocator()
months = plt.matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator()
yearsFmt = plt.matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y')
monthsFmt = plt.matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%b')

axis_1.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
axis_1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
axis_1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
axis_1.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(monthsFmt)

axis_1.tick_params(axis="x", which="both", rotation=45)
axis_1.tick_params(axis="x", length=5, which='minor')
axis_1.tick_params(axis="x", length=24, which='major')
axis_1.set_xlim([datetime.date(2022, 4, 1), datetime.date(2023, 7, 1)])

m2 = r"$\mathrm{\mathsf{m}}^{-2}$"
axis_1.set_ylabel("Avg. Mussel density (ind/ "+m2+")", rotation=90)
axis_1.grid(color='#EEEEEE', which='both', axis='y',zorder=0)
```

Comment: What exactly is `yerror`? It is not at all obvious, I assure you, and it is nowhere in your image, I am sure your example doesn't contain it. The naming of the columns are also confusing, but I guess SE is "standard error" and SD is "standard deviation". Also please don't share data as an image, it makes reproducing the data difficult, as you force whoever wants to help you to retype it, it is tedious labor and wastes time, time they might have spent debugging your code.

Comment: I have edited the description and code according to your questions/opinions.